Why do I see packets arrivals in tcpdump that I explicitly DROP-ed in ip6tables?
Playing around with ip6tables.
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -d fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx -j DROP

Then I try to ping the address and see tcpdump as follows
$ ping fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%eth0
$ sudo tcpdump icmp6 -i eth0 -n -vvv

The ping does not showing the data transfer, but tcpdump succesfully reports packet arrival:
11:02:32.832443 IP6 (flowlabel 0xff034, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 
fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx > fe80::yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 78, seq 7

I expected that the filter table's INPUT chain does not let the packet even be seen by tcpdump and discard it earlier. At which level tcpdump actually works comparing to iptables?

See https://serverfault.com/questions/233302/will-tcpdump-see-packets-that-are-being-dropped-by-iptables
